# How can I say this in other words?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-meaning

Recently I took a personality test and got some good results. However, there was a part of the full description that I didn't understand. I'd like to know how I can say this text in other words, must of all, since "and they spare..." Here's the line:

Ultimately, though, their senses of responsibility and dedication set the tone, and they spare no effort in noting to this distinction moving forward, the consequences having been demonstrated as real.

Answer (score 1):

> Ultimately, though, their senses of responsibility and dedication set
>   the tone, and they **do everything in their power** to note this distinction
>   moving forward, the consequences having been demonstrated as real

Comment: Since we cannot reply" thanks" in the forum... Danke

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately though, their sense of responsibility and dedication set the tone, with all efforts being made to keep this distinction at the forefront of every mind as a sign of moving forward, the consequences having been demonstrated as real. ?